# PGFPlots and Listings incompatibility?

Tags: pgfplots, listings

I'm using ` as my short inline listing delimiter. This compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={\lstDeleteShortInline{`}}, execute at end picture={\lstMakeShortInline{`}}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\lstMakeShortInline{`}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node{Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this throws an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={\lstDeleteShortInline{`}}, execute at end picture={\lstMakeShortInline{`}}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\lstMakeShortInline{`}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the error is this:

```
Package Listings Error: ` is not a short reference for \lstinline.
```

Is there a way to use both pgfplots and backtick delimited inline code snippets in a document?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that listings doesn't want to deactivate a shortcut that is already deactivated. And as pgfplots nests pictures you get an error. You can write your own deactivated macro that avoid the double setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand\deactivemyshortinline{%
 \expandafter\ifx\csname lst@ShortInlineOldCatcode\string`\endcsname\relax
  \else  
   \lstDeleteShortInline{`}%
 \fi}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={execute at begin picture={\deactivemyshortinline}}, execute at end picture={\lstMakeShortInline{`}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\lstMakeShortInline{`}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```